# Where has the community from Avidgamers (1 & 2) migrated to?

Tags: history-of-gaming, online-roleplaying, play-by-post

Where has the community from Avidgamers (1 & 2) migrated to?

The original Avidgamers.com was teeming with personal RP site. There was a conversion/migration to a new ag2.avidgamers.com site, but it unfortunately has serious lacks in functionality. Who/What took over when ag2 collapsed along with ag1?

Comment: [AGeans](http://ageans.tatelu.com/) appears to be a forum for former AG members. I can't judge whether that's where the community *went*, but it certainly seems like that's what someone intended for it to be.

Comment: Discuss validity of this question on this [meta post](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1487/1084)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering that the conversion/migration from www.avidgamers.com was to a subdomain of the original domain to ag2.avidgamers.com... it wasn't much of a migration.

It's been 5 years... everything went dark in 2007.

From the few posts I've read where people were asking about the site and where it went/why it went down, there doesn't appear to be any single site that members migrated to.  They seemed to drift to many of the other sites that are out there, without any majority going to one single place.

So, no one really took over when avidgamers.com collapsed.  Or rather, when the domain expired, it was [purchased through dotster.com](http://www.who.is/whois/avidgamers.com/) and [hosted on a domain parking service](http://www.who.is/nameserver/ns1.voodoo.com/) called [VooDoo.com](http://www.voodoo.com/).  No single site rose to the challenge or managed to attract the community that was at Avidgamer.

Answer (score 6):

Actually.... early this year, an individual decided to recreate Avid Gamers on  [avid-gamers.com ,](http://avid-gamers.com/)  however, after only a few months of attention, in rolled trolls, haters, and drama. It should be no surprise that a service for all-ages attracts immature folk. The creator of this rendition had enough and threw in the towel, shutting down the site. A different site, [ageans.tatelu.com](http://ageans.tatelu.com/) sprouted up, which seems to be a hang-out community for its former denziens.

[Goodpixie.net](http://goodpixie.net/) claims to be working on its own reincranation.

Given the pattern, I have no doubt there will be more projects in the future. But given the work involved in programming (you know what I mean), there is no telling whether or not any of these projects will actually succeed, release, and open - or even live very long after that.

As for where these folks are now, some no longer care about literate roleplaying / collaborative writing, while some do. Roleplay directories and resource sites sprout up here and there and are frequented by roleplay folks seeking services and comradery. Your biggest chance at finding old friends are to scout the resource sites for old AGers. [RPG-D](http://rpg-directory.com/) is the biggest, longest standing, and most active of all of the directories, so it might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the info. It's been quite a while since 07, but I had tons of fun with a community that was part of the original AG - even though I prefer games with graphics.

Comment: Edit: Goodpixie.net is now up and running.